# Extracting two values from the output of a command

Tags: shell-script

I have a script that conducts a Whois lookup on each domain in a list and I need to extract the creation date and the expiration date.  I have the first part but can't seem to get the expiration date also.  I don't want to run the domain through `whois` twice...

```
while IFS="," read domain rdate; do                     # Domain name and received date 
        cdate=( $(whois $domain | grep -m 1 -i Creation| awk -F" " '{print $3}') )
                # Harvest creation date from whois record for each domain 
                # expdate=??????
        printf "$domain,$cdate,$expdate \n"
done < "temp1.txt" 2> /dev/null # Sets the file to read in from and suppress error messages
```

I tried to set the whois as "whod" like so, with no luck:

```
whod=$(whois $domain|awk '{print $0}')
expdate=( $(echo $whod |grep -m 1 -i 'Expiration Date' | awk -F" " '{print $3}') )
echo $expdate
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there's no point in `awk '{print $0}'`, that just prints each input line. Use `whod=$(whois "$domain")` instead. Anyway, your main problem is that you're not quoting your variables. This causes all sorts of issues, most importantly that when you `echo $whod`, what you get is a single line with all the data. Therefore, your `awk '{print $3}'` is being applied to this line (shorted for clarity):

```
Whois Server Version 2.0 Domain names in the .com and .net [ ... ]
```

And the 3rd word is `Version` which, presumably, is what you get. You're also using arrays (`expdate=( $( echo $whod ... ) )`) and I don't understand why. Can there be multiple matches? Anyway, a working version of your script is:

```
while IFS="," read domain rdate; do
  whod="$(whois "$domain")"
  cdate="$(echo "$whod" | grep -m 1 -i Creation| awk -F" " '{print $3}')"
  expdate="$(echo "$whod" |grep -m 1 -i 'Expiration Date' | awk -F" " '{print $3}')"
  printf "$domain,$cdate,$expdate \n"
done < "temp1.txt"
```